# How to produce chunks of sliding windows while iterating over a time series?

Tags: python, time-series, append, chunks

EDITED:

I have a time series let's say `ts = [[0 0][1 1][2 2][3 3][4 4][5 5][6 6][7 7][8 8]]` and I want to slit in the following two sequences:

```
 X = [[[[0][1]][[1][2]][[2][3]]] [[[1][2]][[2][3]][[3][4]]] [[[2][3]][[3][4]][[4][5]]] [[[3][4]][[4][5]][[5][6]]] [[[4][5]][[5][6]][[6][7]]] [[[5][6]][[6][7]][[7][8]]]] 
y = [[3][4][5][6][7][8]]
```

X is the sequence of chunks of three two-steps-sliding windows while y is its features.
My strategy was to employ the following methods, first:

```
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
        X, y = list(), list()
        for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
            end_ix = i + n_steps
            prev_end_ix = end_ix - 1
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
            if end_ix > len(sequences):
                break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
            seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1], sequences[prev_end_ix:end_ix, -1]
            X.append(seq_x)
            y.append(seq_y)
        return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

Which retorns:

```
X =[[[0][1]] [[1][2]] [[2][3]] [[3][4]] [[4][5]] [[5][6]] [[6][7]] [[7][8]]] 
y = [[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]]
```

And then I apply the following two methods to obtain the desired output:

```
def separar_uni_X(sequencia, n_passos):
    X = list()
    for i in range(len(sequencia)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_passos
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequencia):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x = sequencia[i:end_ix, :]
        X.append(seq_x)
    return np.array(X)

def separar_uni_y(sequencia, n_passos):
    y = list()
    for i in range(len(sequencia)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_passos
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequencia):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_y = sequencia[i:end_ix, :]
        y.append(seq_y[-1])
    return np.array(y)
```

PROBLEM: The problem is that in order to obtain the desired output it has to store the data from the first method to the second two and, when the sequence is too long, it exceeds the memory capacity. In order to handle this drawback breaking down the process in subprocesses I've used this method:

```
def split_sequence_3D(sequences, n_steps, batch_size):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
    # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        prev_end_ix = end_ix - 1
    # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
    # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1], sequences[prev_end_ix:end_ix, -1]
        sub_X, sub_y = [], []
        for j in range(batch_size):
            sub_X.append(seq_x)
            sub_y.append(seq_y)
        X.append(sub_X)
        y.append(sub_y[-1])    
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

Which gives me the wrong output, for obvious reasons:

```
X = [[[[0][1]][[0][1]][[0][1]]] [[[1][2]][[1][2]][[1][2]]] [[[2][3]][[2][3]][[2]   [3]]] [[[3][4]][[3][4]][[3][4]]] [[[4][5]][[4][5]][[4][5]]] [[[5][6]][[5][6]][[5 [6]]] [[[6][7]][[6][7]][[6][7]]] [[[7][8]][[7][8]][[7][8]]]] 
y = [[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]]
```

I have extensively looked for an alternative and haven't found it.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Interesting question... I was looking for somethinf similar to it but I don't know how to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've taken really pain to solve your problem, which was mine as well. But the solution, at last, turned out to be kind of simple. My solution was to make sliding window iterator to slide as well.

```
def input_3D(sequencia, lote, janela):
        if lote > len(sequencia):
            raise ValueError('Tamanho do lote maior que o conjunto dos dados')
        if janela > len(sequencia):
            raise ValueError('Tamanho da janela maior que o conjunto dos dados')    
        X_, y_ = [], []
        for j in range (len(sequencia)):
            if j+lote+janela > len(sequencia):
                break
            X, y = [], []
            for i in range (j,j+lote,1):
                end_ix = i+janela
                prev_end_ix = end_ix - 1
                seq_x, seq_y = sequencia[i:end_ix, :-1], sequencia[prev_end_ix:end_ix, -1]
                X.append(np.array(seq_x))
                y.append(np.array(seq_y[-1]))
            X_.append(np.array(X))
            y_.append(np.array(y[-1]))
        return np.array(X_), np.array(y_)
```

Suppose your input is:

```
arr_x = list(range(0,100))
arr_y = list(range(0,100))
arr = np.stack([arr_x,arr_y])
arr = arr.T
```

Then your output is gonna be:

```
[[[[ 0]
   [ 1]
   [ 2]
   ...
   [ 7]
   [ 8]
   [ 9]]

  [[ 1]
   [ 2]
   [ 3]
   ...
   [ 8]
   [ 9]
   [10]]

  [[ 2]
   [ 3]
   [ 4]
   ...
   [ 9]
   [10]
   [11]]

  [[ 3]
   [ 4]
   [ 5]
   ...
   [10]
   [11]
   [12]]]

...

 [[[86]
   [87]
   [88]
   ...
   [93]
   [94]
   [95]]

  [[87]
   [88]
   [89]
   ...
   [94]
   [95]
   [96]]

  [[88]
   [89]
   [90]
   ...
   [95]
   [96]
   [97]]

  [[89]
   [90]
   [91]
   ...
   [96]
   [97]
   [98]]]] [12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 
 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You’ve saved my life! :)